# Integer hypot without overflow

Tags: floating-point, precision, numerical-methods, integer-overflow

How to calculate [hypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot) of two integers, each less than 2^63, so that at no step any intermediate computation does not overflow 64-bits? (such as `x^2+y^2` in the traditional approach).

The linked article mentions a floating-point algorithm, which is not possible to use because of that `t = t/x;` as it is 0 for integers.

The closest algorithm I could find is from [here](http://karthik.com/darcs/netrek-server/Vanilla/robotd/util.c) but unfortunately it is not precise enough:

```
int ihypot(xd1, yd1)
   double xd1, yd1;
{
   register     x1 = (int)xd1,
                y1 = (int)yd1,
                x2 = 0, 
                y2 = 0;

   if ((x2 -= x1) < 0) x2 = -x2;
   if ((y2 -= y1) < 0) y2 = -y2;
   return (x2 + y2 - (((x2>y2) ? y2 : x2) >> 1) );
}
```

Comment: What, you changed the question to be about 64-bit integers now?!

Comment: @PascalCuoq It was never about 32-bit in the first place, it was about overflow and the 32-bit was just an example.

Comment: why do you declare the function parameters that way?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I posted a verbatim copy of the content from the above link.

Comment: @user22698 Good, replace 32 by 64 and 64 by 128 in my answer then. “32-bit processor” becomes “64-bit processor” and “32 * 32 -> 64” becomes “64 * 64 -> 128”. I am glad you took the time to change it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Unfortunately that still does not satisfy the "does not overflow 64-bits" bit.

Comment: You want to compute the precise result of sqrt(x^2 + y^2) for N-bit inputs. This involves using multi-precision arithmetic to implement 2N-bit multiplication and 2N+1-bit addition and sqrt. What else do you need?

Comment: @PascalCuoq True, and I know this. True, if I were to use the traditional formula, which is why I try to avoid it. What I would like to know is whether there is another way of computing hypotenuse of two integers which does not involve overflowing to 2N-bits. It might be even ok to loose bit or two in precision (but not 17 like you proposed below). The example I provided is good hint at what I'm after.

Comment: How do you compute the square root ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root), why?

Comment: Iterations with divisions are costly. Can't you consider a floating-point version anyway ?

Comment: What about rewriting the expression as follows: http://quicklatex.com/cache3/78/ql_27a64d56f9ff5b2bd0523fef2140b178_l3.png
Each number here in the computation can be done before hitting the 2^64 mark

Answer (score 0):

You can always start from the equivalent mathematical formula when implementing with integers:

r = 2<sup>-30</sup> * (x * sqrt(2<sup>30</sup> + 2<sup>30</sup> * y / x))

A typical 32-bit processor should give you access to a 64 / 32 -> 32 division with the input provided in two registers. This division can be used to compute 2<sup>30</sup> * y / x. Your programming language may or may not give you access to it. Do not under-estimate the skill of optimizing compilers when generating 32-bit code for computations involving 64-bit intermediate results.

Similarly, the typical 32-bit processor should provide a 32 * 32 -> 64 multiplication for “x * …”, with the result in two registers.

The final multiplication by 2<sup>-30</sup> amounts to shifting and or-ing the two registers in which the 32 * 32 -> 64 multiplication left its result.

GCC [almost](https://godbolt.org/g/TQkjzs) manages to generate simple code using only 32-bit instructions, but it drops the ball at one point and calls an external multi-precision division function:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t integer_sqrt(uint32_t);

/*@ requires x >= y; */
uint32_t hypot(uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
  return integer_sqrt(0x40000000 + (uint32_t) ((uint64_t)y * 0x40000000 / x)) * (uint64_t) x / 0x40000000 ;
}
```

32-bit assembly result:

```
hypot:
        pushl   %edi
        pushl   %esi
        xorl    %edi, %edi
        pushl   %ebx
        movl    16(%esp), %ebx
        movl    %edi, %edx
        xorl    %edi, %edi
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    36(%esp), %esi
        pushl   %edi
        pushl   %ebx
        shldl   $30, %esi, %edx
        movl    %esi, %eax
        sall    $30, %eax
        pushl   %edx
        pushl   %eax
        call    __udivdi3
        addl    $20, %esp
        addl    $1073741824, %eax
        pushl   %eax
        call    integer_sqrt
        mull    %ebx
        addl    $16, %esp
        popl    %ebx
        popl    %esi
        shrdl   $30, %edx, %eax
        popl    %edi
        ret
```

Edit:

If you only want to use 32*32->32 multiplication, you'll have to compute N=log2(x) and, if N>15, normalize x and y by shifting them right by N-15 (shifting the end result left by the same amount), in effect implementing the formula:

r = 2<sup>N-15</sup> * sqrt((x / 2<sup>N-15</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + (y / 2<sup>N-15</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)

If N≤1, just use the usual formula r = sqrt(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I not sure this works for me: isn't the `2^30 * y` a problem? If I could multiply `y` so that it overflows 32-bits I could well use `y * y` which I try to avoid. I mean `2^30 * 2^30 + 2^30 * 2^30 < 2^64`. And 32 bits was just an example, what if I needed 64 bits? But it might well be I did not fully understand your answer...

Comment: @user22698 If you started from the normal formula sqrt(y\*y + x\*x) and used 64-bit operations throughout, you would need 64-bit addition and 64-bit sqrt. This solution only relies on 32 * 32 -> 64 multiplication and on 64 / 32 -> 32 division (and bit manipulations), which every practical 32-bit processor has. The only problem is getting access to these 32 * 32 -> 64 and 64 / 32 -> 32 operations from a high-level programming language. GCC almost manages to translates my C code to simple 32-bit operations, despite it using 64-bit types.

Comment: @user22698 Also if you used 64-bit operations throughout and started from the formula sqrt(y\*y + x\*x) you would have a risk of overflow in the addition.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I was hoping that there was a way to avoid the overflow (say, 32->64), even if it's fast. I've updated the question to making more clear. I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: @user22698 If you only want to use 32*32->32 multiplication, you'll have to compute N=log2(x) and, if N>15, normalize x and y by shifting them right by N-15 (shifting the end result left by the same amount).

Comment: That looses precision, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite the given expression so that each after each operation lesser than `2^64`. For example:

> [image: Rewrite]

By taking the square root before multiplication, you can make sure that the individual numbers never exceed `2^64`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using floating point, you can use the expression

```
a/cos(atan2(b,a))
```

where `a` and `b` are the inputs

Comment: or without division, b*sin(atan2(b,a))